# Unit Testing a Put With Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, dbcontext, put

I am attempting to unit test a PUT Request by checking values. However, I run into one simple issue. I have a test context like such:

```
class TestAppContext : ContextInterface
{

        public DbSet<User> Users {get; set;}
        public DbSet<Request> Requests { get; set; }

        public TestAppContext()
        {
            this.Users = new TestUsersDbSet();
            this.Requests = new TestRequestsDbSet();
        }

        public int SaveChanges(){
            return 0;
        }
        public void MarkAsModified(Object item) {

        }

        public void Dispose() { }     
}
```

When running a PUT with a DbContext the `Entry(item).State` is set to `EntityState.Modified` in the `MarkAsModified` method, then changes the changes are saved. How do I emulate this in my test context so that the DbSet reflects the changes from the PUT request?

I've gotten as far as doing this:

```
public void MarkAsModified(Object item) {
  if (item.GetType() == typeof(User))
  {

  }
  else if (item.GetType() == typeof(Request))
  {

  }
}
```

So that I can determine what is being modified, but how do I actually save the changes into the DbSet for that record?

Both records are identified on a variable `id` which is an `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your test context just keep a `List<Object> markedAsModified` field, then in the call to `MarkAsModified` add the object to that list if it doesn't already exist. Then in your test you can have `Assert` statements the check the contents of that list to make sure the right objects were passed to that function..

Comment: Why would you need to? Does the calling code inspect the state after it calls `MarkedAsModified`? If not, then there is no need, and your test only needs to check that `MarkedAsModified` was called with the right objects.

Comment: In my test, I want to assert that the change takes place. Is there a way to update the DbSet directly?

Comment: Maybe I'm confused about what you are testing then. I thought that `TestAppContext` is a fake context that you use so that you can test other code that talks to your production context. But it sounds like you are wanting to test the code in `TestAppContext`?

If you write code to make a change to DbSet and verify that the change takes place, you're not testing your own code, you're testing Microsoft's implementation of DbSet. That's not the sort of thing that is usually valuable for unit tests.

Comment: @Erik It sort of makes sense if you want to do some integration testing(i.e. not a unit test in a purest sense), where you test business rules that might be a part of the webapi actions, or you want consistency checks across multiple API calls.

Comment: Yeah, but the OP has mocked his EF context with a test context, then he should only have a single API entry point to mark an object as modified, and it's the method in question. At least that's my understanding of the situation.

Comment: @Erik I think you have described correctly what approach has has attempted.  I think it's just a matter that the approach he has taken isn't going to support his goal very well.  My point was **what** he's trying to accomplish makes sense, but not necessarily **how** he is going about trying to get there.

Comment: @steventnorris Most approaches to mocking EF don't support this scenario very well.  Usually things like `SaveChanges` do nothing, because to make things like `MarkAsModified` and `SavingChanges` behave as they would in production would almost require you emulate the entire DB layer, which would run the full gammut of emulating constraints, etc.  If you want to be able to modify/save and then Assert the results, it's probably better those kind of tests be done against a actual DB (localdb) with a `Seed` method: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/seed-database-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: @AaronLS Yes, it makes sense in a broad context but in this specific context I don't think it does. From browsing the source code for Entity Framework it looks as though the state of the entities are stored in a private variable inside the DbContext object, not in the individual DbSet objects. So if you're mocking the context, there is nothing to update in the DbSet objects anyway.